# How to determine time series similarity by magnitude and pattern?

Tags: time-series, similarities, hierarchical-clustering, dynamic-time-warping

### Context

I know that Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) can be used to assign a dissimilarity score between two time series. Based on the distance matrix of DTW scores, I can cluster data with say, Hierarchical Clustering (HC). But in my observation, the similarly clustered series are similar in pattern, not necessarily in magnitude.

So, my question is: how can I determine time series similarity by both magnitude and pattern.

### Example

I used the gaminder data in `R` to determine similarities between countries in terms of 3 variables: life expectancy, GDP, and population using DTW. Then I clustered them using HC.

Following shows the resulting dendrogram (I cut the tree in 8 clusters):

[image]

As an example, note here:

1. Yemen and Oman are most similar in a cluster, followed by Syria, Jordan and Westbank & Gaza
2. Bahrain and Mongolia are most similar in another cluster, followed by Phillipines

The following shows a scatter plot with `year` on x-axis and `lifeExp`ectancy on y-axis. The number on each facet represents a cluster. Notice that in cluster 7 Yemen and Oman are similar by pattern, BUT other countries in the cluster seem to be similar to Oman in terms of life expectancy (i.e. magnitude). The same is seen in cluster 2 and 4. Others have less number of members.

How can I find similarity by magnitude and pattern?

[image]

#### R Code to reproduce plot

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dtwclust))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(factoextra))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gapminder))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggrepel))

scale_this <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
}


df <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(continent == "Asia") %>% # countries in Asia only
  group_by(country) %>%           # scaling the vars for each country
  mutate(lifeExp = scale_this(lifeExp),
         pop = scale_this(pop),
         gdpPercap = scale_this(gdpPercap)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()


df_matrix <- df %>% 
  split(.$country, drop = T) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ .x[, c("lifeExp",    # names of all vars
                       "pop",
                       "gdpPercap"
                      )]) %>% 
  purrr::map(as.matrix) 


clusters_gp <- df_matrix %>% 
  tsclust(., 
          k = 8L,                 # assuming clusters
          distance = "dtw_basic", # this is dtw score
          seed = 390,             # to reproduce results
          type="hierarchical",    # type of clustering
          control = hierarchical_control(method = "ward.D")) 


Gps <- as.data.frame(cutree(clusters_gp, k = 8)) # num of clusters
colnames(Gps) <- "Gp"
Gps$country <- row.names(Gps)
row.names(Gps) <- NULL


## Getting the clustering info into the original data
gapminder_Asia <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(continent == "Asia") %>% 
  left_join(x=., y=Gps, by = "country")


### Select 15 countries at random to label on plot
set.seed(123)

selected_countries <- gapminder_Asia %>% 
  group_by(Gp) %>% 
  select(country) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  sample_n(size = 4, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pull(country) %>% 
  unique()


sc_data <- gapminder_Asia %>% 
  filter(year == 1982,
         country %in% selected_countries)



### lifeExp
ggplot(data = gapminder_Asia,
       aes(x = year, y = lifeExp)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=country), color = "grey") +
  facet_wrap(~ Gp) +
  geom_line(data = gapminder_Asia %>% 
              filter(country %in% selected_countries),
            aes(group=country)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = sc_data,
            aes(label = country),
            box.padding = 1,
            nudge_x = .15,
            nudge_y = .5,
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.015, "npc")),
            hjust = 0
            ) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Pattern, look at the cross correlation between the time series. Magnitude, look at its average magnitude, and use something like a squared difference as a (dis)similarity metric.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Oxonon. But wouldn't they provide two, conflicting measures of dissimilarity? Is there 1 method that can combine the two?